# Dependency Property for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, dependency-properties

Is there any similar strategy as dependency property in WPF to use in ASP.NET?

I want to create an UserControl in ASP.NET with a custom property, named for example "Car" then in the view I want to do something like this:

```
<CarControl Car="Ferrari" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: No. ASP.Net is a Web technology. It produces HTML, and HTML is nowhere near the quality and ease of use for Data-Centric development of XAML. it does not have the notion of DataBinding and you need a bunch of horrible javascript in order to do anything with it. You will have to get used to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your sample, I suspect that the main point is the ability to set the property in markup. This is possible with the following approach, though it does not have too much in common with a Dependency Property in WPF.

In your UserControl class in the CodeBehind file (named UserControlName.ascx.vb), you can add a property Car that you can set in the markup. You can open this file in the context menu by choosing `View Code`.

**C#**

```
public partial class CarControl : UserControl
{
    // ...
    public string Car { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
Public Partial Class CarControl 
    Inherits UserControl

    ' ...

    Public Property Car As String

    ' ...

End Class
```

**Markup**

```
<My:CarControl ID="MyId" runat="server" Car="Ferrari" />
```

Comment: I don't get it. How can I change Car property in the View?

Comment: @Seva: I've updated the answer. Do you use WebForms?

Comment: wow, thats great! Even simpler than in WPF. Thanks.
Yes, I am using WebForms.